# Hover effect fails for Font Awesome (4.7) Icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors, font-awesome

For the following code in the HTML file:

```
<div style="float:right">
  <a id="playbtnid">
    <i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-2x" id="play" onclick="play()"></i>
  </a> 
</div>
```

and the followinng CSS:

```
.fa-play-circle:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

The hover effect does not work; I have alternatively also tried to use

```
div a i:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

and it still doesn't work on my browser, which is updated to the latest Google Chrome.

Here is a JSFiddle link with the same code as above:
http://jsfiddle.net/0u812ftz/12/#&togetherjs=QfG8z8OeVL

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: your code works fine on link your provided

Comment: yes but it doesn't work on my local host machine

Comment: Works fine on my machine (Windows 10 + Chrome  83.0.4103.97)

Comment: Ah are you accessing your website through a url like `http://localhost`? Then you're probably hitting security walls or http vs https or other localhost woes. Check the Chrome Developer Console for errors or warnings. And check in the Network tab if any resources are being blocked (like the stylesheets)

Comment: Yes you're right! Fixed, thanks!